# Several input streams vs one input stream with seekg

Tags: c++, inputstream, seekg

I have a large (text) file that is divided into d "chunks". The user can read the next line from either of these chunks - the order is not specified. The file is not changed in the process.

There are two obvious solutions: Maintaining d input streams (one per chunk) or maintaining the current stream positions and jumping from chunk to chunk via the seekg-method with a single stream.

Is there any reason to assume that either method is (much) better than the other (in terms of efficiency)?

Comment: I imagine the answer depends upon usage and how many chunks you're talking about. You might have to test it. I also imagine it varies by platform.

Comment: (1) From a design point of view, seek does not sound promising - evil centralization. I would use different streams. (2) If the performance is so critical, just run some tests.

Comment: You could also use functions depending on platform specific features, like boost's [memory mapped files](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html). Just memory map the file and jump back and forth using iterators and rely on the platform for efficiency. Posix's `mmap` does a good job and I assume the Windows variant does too.